# Push Notification not received while app is in foreground using firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification by using FCM, While the app is in suspended mode (App is closed) notification is coming but while app in foreground mode (App is open) notification not coming.

Even didreciveRemote notification method is not calling.

Comment: Examples of your code would be welcomed to illustrate the issue.

Comment: When the app is in foreground, notification will not come. But didreciveRemote method will be triggered. Try to post some code to analyze the issue.

Comment: try this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/286#issuecomment-304978967